# How to find where a process started in elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am using observer in elixir and the following is the snapshot of an Application [under applications tab]:

[image: snapshot of observer]

I need to exit these processes once their work is done. Somehow, I am not able to figure out where some of the processes are originating. Is there a way in elixir/erlang to figure out the module/function where a particular process was created?

Suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you must always have the process's PID or its reference name.

```
Process.info/2
```

will give you information about that Process. You may get more documentation and information on how this function works in the Erlang's function it is calling:

[process_info-2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2)

There are also arity 1 variants: [Process Docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Process.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
[erlang:process_info(Pid, initial_call) || Pid <- erlang:processes()].
```

But note that `gen_server`, etc., all have the same initial call, so you need to dig a little deeper.

The following is adapted from https://gist.github.com/rlipscombe/a8e87583d47799170f8b:

```
lists:map(
    fun(Pid) ->
        InitialCall = case erlang:process_info(Pid, initial_call) of
            {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,A}} ->
                case erlang:process_info(Pid, dictionary) of
                    {dictionary, D} ->
                        proplists:get_value('$initial_call', D, undefined);    
                    _ ->
                        {proc_lib,init_p,A}
                end;
            {initial_call,{erlang,apply,A}} ->
                case erlang:process_info(Pid, current_function) of
                    {current_function,MFA} -> MFA;
                    _ -> {erlang,apply,A}
                end;
            {initial_call,IC} ->
                IC;
            Other ->
                Other
        end,
        {Pid, InitialCall}
    end, erlang:processes()).
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`process_info/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-1) you can get a list of process information from which `initial_call` and `current_function` could help you to find the initial function call with which the process was spawned and the current function call of the process respectively.

Also `process_info(Pid, initial_call)` and `process_info(Pid, current_function)` functions are using as shortcut.